# how to write custom error handler for xsd validation for jaxb object

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xsd-validation

I want validate my JAXB object using xsd And want to return proper error message. But the error message i m able to get is :

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'applicant-dto'. One of '{applicant-id}' is expected.
>
> [cvc-pattern-valid: Value '12345670' is not facet-valid with respect
>   to pattern '^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$' for type 'ssn'., cvc-type.3.1.3:
>   The value '12345670' of element 'ssn' is not valid.]

I want to get proper error message. Can anybody help me out to figure out same.

my xsd is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="applicant" type="applicantDTO" />

  <xs:complexType name="applicantDTO" >
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="applicant-id" type="xs:long" minOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="first-name" type="name" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="middle-name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="last-name" type="name" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="ssn" type="ssn" minOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="date-of-birth" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="name">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z ]{3,30}"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="ssn">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="^\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}$"></xs:pattern>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

My JAXB Object is

> ApplicantDTO

for validating it with XSD I m writing below code

```
@Test
    public void testValidateApplicantDTO() throws Exception {
        ApplicantDTO eDTO = getApplicantDTO();
        SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI); 
        Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("src/test/resources/applicant.xsd")); 

        Validator validator =  schema.newValidator();
        CustomErrorHandler errorHandler = new CustomErrorHandler();
        validator.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ApplicantDTO.class);
        JAXBSource source = new JAXBSource(jc, eDTO);
        validator.validate(source);

        System.out.println(errorHandler.getErrors());
    }
```

I have written my custom error hadler

CustomErrorHandler

```
public class CustomErrorHandler extends DefaultHandler  {

    List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("CustomErrorHandler.warning()");
    }

    @Override
    public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("CustomErrorHandler.error()");
        errors.add(exception.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("CustomErrorHandler.fatalError()");
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        System.out.println("CustomErrorHandler.startElement()");
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
        System.out.println("CustomErrorHandler.endElement()");
    }

    /**
     * @return the errors
     */
    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return this.errors;
    }

    /**
     * @param errors the errors to set
     */
    public void setErrors(List<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

the error list return to me with error message :

Comment: The following may help: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: i am able to achieve same but the problem is the error message is not proper. I want error message should be proper.